# Drop rows after particular year Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe that has years in the following format:

```
2018-19
2017-18
```

The years are object data type. I want to change the type of this column to datetime, then drop all rows before 1979-80. However, I tried to do that and I got formatting errors. What is the correct, or better way, of doing this?

```py
BOS['Season'] = pd.to_datetime(BOS['Season'], format = '%Y%y')
```

I am quite new to Python, so I could appreciate it if you can tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think here is simpliest compare years separately, e.g. before `-`:

```
print (BOS)
    Season
0  1979-80
1  2018-19
2  2017-18


df = BOS[BOS['Season'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int) < 2017]
print (df)
    Season
0  1979-80
```

**Details**:

First is splited value by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to lists and then seelcted first lists:

```
print (BOS['Season'].str.split('-'))
0    [1979, 80]
1    [2018, 19]
2    [2017, 18]
Name: Season, dtype: object

print (BOS['Season'].str.split('-').str[0])
0    1979
1    2018
2    2017
Name: Season, dtype: object
```

Or convert both years to separately columns:

```
BOS['start'] = pd.to_datetime(BOS['Season'].str.split('-').str[0],  format='%Y').dt.year
BOS['end'] =  BOS['start'] + 1
print (BOS)
    Season  start   end
0  1979-80   1979  1980
1  2018-19   2018  2019
2  2017-18   2017  2018
```

Comment: @abhivemp - it is first values of lists after split by `-`

Comment: if I have a list of 30 dataframes similar to BOS, how would I make this change? When I do it, nothing happens:

Comment: I can make a new question about that if that's better

Comment: @abhivemp - I cannot see comment ;)

Comment: if I have a list of 30 dataframes similar to BOS, how would I make this change? When I do it, nothing happens or I get a str access error

Comment: @abhivemp - I think the best is create new question, please add 2-3 data samples with expcted output.

Comment: here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412697/iterate-through-a-list-of-dataframes-to-drop-particular-rows-pandas

Answer (score 1):

I would have use [`.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) accessor of Series to select the part of the date I wish to keep, to insert it into the [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function. Then, the select with [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and boolean mask becomes easy.

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {
    'date' : ['2016-17', '2017-18', '2018-19', '2019-20']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#       date
# 0  2016-17
# 1  2017-18
# 2  2018-19
# 3  2019-20

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.slice(0, 4), format='%Y')
print(df)
#         date
# 0 2016-01-01
# 1 2017-01-01
# 2 2018-01-01
# 3 2019-01-01


df = df.loc[ df['date'].dt.year < 2018 ]
print(df)
#           date
# 0 2016-01-01
# 1 2017-01-01
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, slicing would remove everything after the hyphen and then you convert those to dates?

Comment: Slicing would keep the characters you wish to keep. It's as if you'd do `'2018-19'[0:4]`.