# Iterate through a list of dataframes to drop particular rows Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In my previous question [where I asked to drop particular rows in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410185/drop-rows-after-particular-year-pandas)

With help, I was to drop rows that before 1980. The 'Season' column (that had the years) were in this format:

```
 2018-19
 2017-18
 This
 list would go
 till 1960
```

In the earlier question(linked) @jezrael gave a solution that helped me drop rows before 1980.

I have a list (called `list`) that has 30 dataframes. I want to iterate through the 30 dataframes and drop all rows before 1980 for every `df`. For instance, one of the items in `list` is `BOS`
if `BOS['Season]` has:

```
 2018-19
 2017-18
 1959-1960
```

I should get

```
2018-19
2017-18
```

And the result like this should be for all dataframes in `list`

This is what I tried, but got errors or nothing would happen:

```py
for df in list:
   df = df[df['Season'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int) > 1980]
```

What's wrong with my code? I am new to python. I thought by assigning `df` to the the change, it would implement it to every '`df` in the `list`

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I have a `list` named as `league`. This list has 30 DataFrames. I looked at jazrael's and IMCoin's solution. Both of them worked. But here is my requirement.

After dropping rows before 1980 for every DataFrame. I want to be able to use that DataFrame directly, and not through the list. Here is what I mean.

```py
#Before Appending to the list
BOS = pd.read_csv(dir+"Boston_Sheet")
# I have 30 different cities, each having a CSV file and making each city have 
# their own DataFrame. So Boston as `BOS`, Chicago as `CHI` and like that 30 cities.
```

All of those 30 city DataFrames have already been appended to the list `league`. 
After filtering the city DataFrame to the conditions above, I want to be able to call `BOS` or `CHI` with the filtered data. This is just so that it will be easy for me developing other functions down the line.

Comment: If that's acceptable to merge all the DataFrames... use `pd.concat(df_list)`, and then, the date filter.

Comment: That was my first idea, but for my application I need these dataframes to be separate

Comment: See my solution if it suits you, your problem is how you iterate through the list.

Answer (score 1):

You need create new list of filtered DataFrames or reaasign old one:

Notice: Dont use variable `list`, because `builtins` (python code word).

```
L = [df[df['Season'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int) > 1980] for df in L]
```

Loop version:

```
output = []
for df in L:
   df = df[df['Season'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int) > 1980]
   output.append(df)
```

If need extract only first integers with length 4:

```
L = [df, df]
L = [df[df['Season'].str.extract('(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float) > 1980] 
          for df in L]

print (L)
[    Season
0  2018-19
1  2017-18,     Season
0  2018-19
1  2017-18]
```

EDIT:

If data have same structure I suggest create one big DataFrame with new column for distinguish cities:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp).assign(City=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]) for fp in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
          Season           City
0        2018-19   Boston_Sheet
1           This   Boston_Sheet
2  list would go   Boston_Sheet
3      till 1960   Boston_Sheet
4        2018-19  Chicago_Sheet
5        2017-18  Chicago_Sheet
6           This  Chicago_Sheet

df1 = df[df['Season'].str.extract('(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float) > 1980]
print (df1)
     Season           City
0   2018-19   Boston_Sheet
4   2018-19  Chicago_Sheet
5   2017-18  Chicago_Sheet

df2 = df1[df1['City'] == 'Boston_Sheet']
print (df2)
    Season          City
0  2018-19  Boston_Sheet

df3 = df1[df1['City'] == 'Chicago_Sheet']
print (df3)
     Season           City
4   2018-19  Chicago_Sheet
5   2017-18  Chicago_Sheet
```

---

If need each DataFrame separate, it is possible by dictionary of DataFrames:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs_dict = {os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0] : pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files}

print (dfs_dict)

print (dfs_dict['Boston_Sheet'])
          Season
0        2018-19
1           This
2  list would go
3      till 1960

print (dfs_dict['Chicago_Sheet'])
0   2018-19
1   2017-18
2      This
```

Then processing in dictionary comprehension:

```
dfs_dict = {k:v[v['Season'].str.extract('(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float) > 1980] 
                 for k, v in dfs_dict.items()}
print (dfs_dict)
{'Boston_Sheet':     Season
0  2018-19, 'Chicago_Sheet':      Season
0   2018-19
1   2017-18}

print (dfs_dict['Boston_Sheet'])
    Season
0  2018-19

print (dfs_dict['Chicago_Sheet'])
     Season
0   2018-19
1   2017-18
```

Comment: So my idea was correct, but I wasn't storing the modified `df`? Is there a way to do this without a new list? (just curious)

Comment: I am getting an error for filtering the dates. I did something similar (made expand true and type as int. Even after I changed it to your suggestion I get a 'KeyError' for Season ?

Comment: @abhivemp - It means there are no column names `Season` in some file, check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43736163). You can test columns names by `for k, v in dfs_dict.items(): print (v.columns.tolist())`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the list in-place :

```py
for index in range(len(df_list)):
    df_list[index] = df_list[index].loc[df_list[index]['Season'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int) > 1980]
```

When you're looping through the list object itself, it creates a new object at each iteration, that's getting erased at each turn.

If you're looping using the length of the list, and accessing your data through the index, you will modify the list itself, and not the copy you made with `for some_copy_item in df_list`.

---

Minimal example :

```py
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    print(arr) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    for number in arr:
        number += 1
    print(arr) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    for idx in range(len(arr)):
        arr[idx] += 1
    print(arr) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Does this mean that if I use `BOS` I won't get the filtered result?

Comment: @adhivemp it just depends of what you want to do. If you have a list, and want to alter it. Use my method. If you have a list, and want to store the new value into a new list, to keep track of the last value, do what jezrael did

Comment: I tried your method. My original list is altered perfectly (I was able to check by printing the list by index). However, when I use the actual DataFrame name to call them (like `BOS`) I get the original DataFrame. Is there something I am doing wrong(First I typed your suggestion by line to understand. After I thought I was doing something wrong, I just copy pasted and I am getting the same result)

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're exactly asking as of right now

Comment: @abhivemp Make a dict.

Comment: make a dict where the keys are the DataFrame names and the values are the filtered data?

Comment: Apologies if it seems this way. I wouldn't say that I have not tried, niether will I say that I have copied your solutions. Perhaps I should learn the much more language before I write some code. Thanks for your input either way :)

Comment: @abhivemp You should accept jezrael answer because I think it covers the whole spectrum of your needs ;)