# Dict 'Key Error' when formatting dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 30 csv files where each file has it's own DataFrame (due to the requirements, I cannot merge the DataFrames). I want to have a dictionary, where the key is the name of the csv file and the value is the DataFrame itself. This is what I have for that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

files = glob.glob('data\*.csv')

roster = {os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0] : pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files}
```

The CSV files have a column called 'Season' where the format is like this: '2018-19', '2017-18' and these values vary file to file. I want to only take rows that's after 1980. With help of jazrael from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412697/iterate-through-a-list-of-dataframes-to-drop-particular-rows-pandas), I was able to use his suggestion. However, I am running into a KeyError. From my understanding, that means I am using the wrong column name or wrong key. However, both of those are correct. This is what my friend jazrael suggested:

```py
dfs_dict = {k:v[v['Season'].str.extract('(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float) > 1980] 
                 for k, v in dfs_dict.items()}
```

And this is my error:

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Season'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8f59bae477f8> in <module>
      1 league = {k:v[v['Season'].str.extract('(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float) > 1980] 
----> 2                  for k, v in league.items()}
      3 
      4 
      5 #BOS[BOS['Season'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int) < 2017

<ipython-input-2-8f59bae477f8> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      1 league = {k:v[v['Season'].str.extract('(\d{4})', expand=False).astype(float) > 1980] 
----> 2                  for k, v in league.items()}
      3 
      4 
      5 #BOS[BOS['Season'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(int) < 2017

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Season'
```

I am quite new to Python, would appreciate it if anyone can explain what I am doing wrong :)

Comment: Did you try *unwinding* that comprehension to a regular for loop and test/inspect the individual statements?

Comment: When you [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect the offending DataFrame, is it what you expected?